# Unit Testing / Test if a function is present within a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I would like to know if there is a way using mocha and chai to test the code for the existence of a whole piece of code, like for instance a function like this.

```
myfunction(arg1) {
    ......
}
```

If the code is present, then the test should return true.

PD: I know that testing for an entire piece of code may look like a nasty thing, but sometimes when conducting a training the students code a lot, and if something is not working we should review the entire set of steps they've done, to avoid that I want to write a test to look for certain pieces of code. I already wrote other tests to check for the existence of arguments, array element length, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'd have to read the file and parse it, searching for whatever you're looking for. You can check an object for a function, `myObj["fn"]`, but I don't know that you can check for code within the function.

Comment: @Guillermo you have never give useful information on your problem.what's the test specification?Precondition?How to exercise?and what are the test context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various ways you can do this with `chai`.

If the function you are testing is on the `global` (`window`) namespace, you can use the following:

```
expect(myfunction).to.exist // asserts target is neither null or undefined`
```

***or***

```
expect(myfunction).to.be.ok // asserts target is truthy
```

Refer to this [handy cheat sheet](https://gist.github.com/yoavniran/1e3b0162e1545055429e) for mocha/chai assertions/expectations.

Comment: I think what he's asking is if he can test to see if someone wrote specific code within the function. So, he wants to see if someone wrote, 
`myFn() {`
   `var i = 0;`
`}`